# How to attach to process using VC6 on win 2003?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, winapi

The 'attach to process' dialogue box on VC6 running on win 2003 (I believe vista as well) has no processes to attach to in it... I've tried logging on as an administrator and running as an administrator but no luck. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug that's been fixed in SP 4. See [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/235434/EN-US/) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Installing the latest service pack helps... doh.